# CCNet Make Version Configurable

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant

I am automating build with CCNEt. The last step of the build is to create a file. Its name will be in the formatAS_V_***1.0.0.1***_DD_MMM_YYY. ***1.0.0.1*** is the version number. This version number will be used in multiple multiple projects. So I want this to be a configurable parameter. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to define a parameter in your CCNET configuration. I [wrote about CCNET parameters](http://enterpriseyness.com/2009/12/continuous-integration-with-cruise-control-net-nant/) a while ago.

Essentially, you can define your parameter using

```
<cb:define KEY=”VALUE” />
```

and then use the parameter using `$(Key)`

Example:

```
<cb:define Version="1.0.0.1" />
```

and then specify you label as `AS_V_$(Version)_DD_MMM_YYY`